# Armstrong Number Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here's a code I wrote for Oracle PL/SQL Armstrong Number

```
declare
num number;
sum number;
temp number;
val number;
begin
num:=&num;
temp:=num;
while temp<>0 loop
val:=trunc(temp mod 10);
sum:=sum +(val*val*val);
temp:=temp/10;
end loop;
if sum=num then
dbms_output.put_line('number is Armstrong');
else
dbms_output.put_line('number is not Armstrong');
end if;
end;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR at line 11: ORA-06550: line 11, column 10: PLS-00103:
>   Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following: ( The
>   symbol "(" was substituted for "+" to continue. ORA-06550: line 11,
>   column 24: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of
>   the following: ) * & - + / at mod remainder rem  ||
>   year day The symbol ")" was substituted for ";" to continue.
>   ORA-06550: line 14, column 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "="
>   when expecting one of the following: (

What have I done wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at MOD:                                                    http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions108.htm#SQLRF00668

Comment: MOD operator can be used as I mentioned, even if I use the MOD function the error persists.

Comment: What are the values of temp and val when this occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sum` is a reserved word in most databases (including Oracle). It's an aggregate function, which is why Oracle's telling you that it's expecting a left parenthesis. Change the name of that variable and the block will work.